# Present experimental status of Moffat's Modified theory of Gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, astronomy, soft-question, experimental-physics

Modified theories of Gravity have been discussed before in this 2-year old question, [Are modified theories of gravity credible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6561/are-modified-theories-of-gravity-credible)

I was going through Moffat's modified gravity, given in http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0506021 , but before investing too much time into it, I wanted to get some clarifications:

1)What is the present experimental status of the theory?

2)I read somewhere that the theory has is free of singularities, is this true?

3)Although I don't know anything about the details of the theory, it seems a little contrived and unnatural to me, with the variable Gravitational constant and all the extra fields in the action. Am I unjustified in thinking this way?