# Isn't Dark Matter just an Indication that Relativity breaks down when describing large masses?

Tags: relativity, dark-matter, modified-gravity

It seems to me that Dark Matter is just an indication that our models of gravity do not scale to the level of galaxies, and thus like Newtonian physics, it is a powerful but incomplete model of the universe. Why do most physicists believe that it is more likely that there is some mysterious previously undetected substance constituting most of the mass in our universe as opposed to limitations in our current models as we scale them up? I am far from an expert in this stuff (more an enthusiastic amateur), so please educate me.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6561/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Dark matter is matter that has a gravitational effect but we cannot see. We don't know why we can't see it but we can measure its existence and their are certain optical effects that are detectable when we look at dark matter clusters.