# A question regarding $f(R)$ Lagrangians

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Consider the class of Lagrangian known as  [$f(R)$ Lagrangians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%28R%29_gravity)  where the Lagrangian is some function $f(R)$,
\begin{equation}
S=\int\sqrt{g}d^4x\ f(R)
\end{equation}
assuming there are no (or ignoring) boundary terms one finds
\begin{equation}
\delta S=\int\sqrt{g}d^4x\left(-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}f(R)+f'(R)R_{\mu\nu}-\left(\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu-g_{\mu\nu}\Box\right)f'(R)\right)\delta g^{\mu\nu}.
\end{equation}
Suppose $f(R)=g^\frac{1}{4}R$.

1. Is there a way to define the covariant derivative of $g^\frac{1}{4}$?
2. Is $f(R)=g^\frac{1}{4}R$ a valid choice?

Comment: In what way is that a problem?

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): Choosing e.g. $f(R)=g^{\frac{1}{4}}R$ would not be a geometrically covariant theory because $f(R)$ would no longer transform as a scalar, i.e. the action would depend on the choice of coordinates.

Comment: More on [$f(R)$ gravity](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=f%28R%29+gravity+is%3Aq), possibly most relevant (which isn't in that search) is [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6561/).

Comment: Actually, thinking about this some more, what is the actual question here?

Comment: Okay. I'll write it more clearly.

Comment: Wouldn't $\nabla_a g^{1/4} = \partial_a g^{1/4}$?

Comment: Furthermore, $f(R) = g^{1/4}R$ is not a function of $R$ (but a function of $R$ and $g$), $f(R) = R^2$ or $f(R) = \sin(R)$ are functions of $R$.

Comment: @JamalS No, since $g^{1/4}$ is not a scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments to the question (v2):

1. Assuming that the connection $\nabla$ is compatible$^1$ with the metric $\nabla_{\lambda}g_{\mu\nu}=0$, then $\nabla_{\lambda}\det g_{\mu\nu}=0$, and therefore e.g. $\nabla_{\lambda}\left|\det g_{\mu\nu}\right|^{\frac{1}{4}}=0$.
2. Choosing e.g. $f(R)=\left|\det g_{\mu\nu}\right|^{\frac{1}{4}}R$ would not be a geometrically covariant theory because [$f(R)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%28R%29_gravity) would no longer transform as a scalar, i.e. the action would depend on the choice of coordinates.

--

$^1$ The [Levi-Civita connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection) is compatible with the metric.

Comment: Perhaps this would be a good place to mention how the Levi-Civita connection acts on (scalar) densities.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249961/2451