# New models for extreme scales?

Tags: astrophysics, galaxies, modified-gravity

Physicists struggling to explain too-fast spinning galaxies with standard models of gravity is weird to me.
If we can accept that normal physics don't apply on a quantum level why shouldn't the same not be a thing on an astronomical level?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6561/2451 and link therein.